# Importing requests module in python using netbeans

Tags: python, macos, netbeans, python-requests

I'm using netbeans to write a simple python program which I need the requests module for, I've downloaded requests through terminal and it all seems to be fine there but netbeans can't seem to find it.

This is the error that it's throwing up:

```
      import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I've tried installing the requests library directly into the python folder but the folder won't let me paste anything into it.

There do seem to be answers on the netbeans forums but their server is down so won't let me on their website to my annoyance!

EDIT

I've tried to run `python setup.py install` as per other answers on the website but had no luck.

EDIT

have tried completely uninstalling python and requests to make sure it wasn't an installation error but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I gave up with requests, as I was using requests to get json data from an API I decided just to go back to the drawing board and start over rather than attempt to fix something that I couldn't work out. I am now using the urllib import and whilst this may not be the most efficient way it works which is the most important thing.

Answer (score 1):

This clearly looks like an error of installation of the request module to some other place than where your netbeans expects when running the code.

In your console run

```
which python
```

Check if this gives the same path as the one set in your netbeans. You can set your path by adding new platform using `Tools > Python Platforms > New:`

I would suggest that you learn bit more about sandboxed environments such as [virtualenv](https://dzone.com/articles/netbeans-ide-virtualenv-your-p). This article shows how you can use a virtualenv to install packages and use the same virtualenv for netbeans so that whatever packages you install in the virtualenv will be available in the netbeans for you to use. For this case, it could be `requests`.

Comment: no luck with this, do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: You might even just try creating a virtualenv and running the code by hand. You can always write code on sublime or pycharm community edition if that's not an issue. I am not much familiar with Netbeans for Python and hardly anyways uses it for writing python.